# Cannot install any packages in R, on manjaro

Tags: r, install.packages, manjaro

I have been trying to install some packages in R through the terminal in my Manjaro machine, but I found that every time I am getting the same error no matter what package I am trying to install.

```
> install.packages("ggplot2")
Warning in install.packages("ggplot2") :
  'lib = "/usr/lib/R/library"' is not writable
Would you like to use a personal library instead? (yes/No/cancel) yes
Would you like to create a personal library
‘/home/"username"/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2’
to install packages into? (yes/No/cancel) yes
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
  libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What's the output of `capabilities()["tcltk"]`?

Comment: How did you install R? If installed via the "normal" means (OS-level package manager), I would have expected the dependency on `tcltk.so` to be satisfied. Try `sudo pacman -S tk` (on the shell console, not in R) to install that dep and see if it works. (I don't use manjaro, I believe that is the correct call.)

Comment: > capabilities()["tcltk"]
    tcltk 
     TRUE

Comment: I have installed the package and now i seem to have a n error showing the "installation of package 'irace' had non-zero exit status", thanks for the help.